# Select all divs except one

Tags: jquery, html

I trying to use jQuery to select all divs except the one with class matching the name of the button the user clicks.
Here's sample HTML:

```
   <button name="apples">Apples</button>
   <button name="oranges">Oranges</button>
   <button name="bananas">Bananas</button>

   <div> //This div is also accidentally targeted
       <div id="apples">
           <img src="" alt"" >
       </div>
       <div id="oranges">
           <img src="" alt"" >
       </div>
       <div id="bananas">
           <img src="" alt"" >
       </div>
   </div>
```

Something like this:

```
   <script>
   $("button").click(function() {
   var name = $(this).attr('name');
   $("div:not('#' + name)").toggle();
   // This works, but it obviously also targets other divs on the page.
   });
   </script>
```

I thought about trying to use classes but seem to be struggling with more complex selectors such as children, parent, closest, etc in combination with the not selector. I've tried --div:not"" > img-- and many other combinations. What should I do?

Comment: use a class on the ones you want to work with....

Comment: how would I write the selector for picking the divs with class but missing the id? I tried this previously but guess I wrote the selector wrong. Should I select divs with class then isolate the ones that do not contain the id?

Comment: String wrapping.... `"div:not('#' + name)"` will literaly stay the same, what you want is `"name"` to become the value of the variable `name`, then do `"div:not(#" + name + ")"` js doesn't care which kind of quote-mark you use, but once you use one, you need to use the same to break the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing I'd do is use a class to identify the elements you want to target, ie

```
<div class="target" id="apples">
    <img src="" alt"" >
</div>
```

Then, combine that class with a `not` filter to match the elements you want

```
$('.target').not('#' + name).toggle()
```